# How to change google charts text color

Tags: html, css

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">';

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Tools', 'Number'],
          ['example1',  $countr1],
          ['example2',     $countr2],



                            ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Available Tools',  
          titleTextStyle: {color: '#FFFFFF'},
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',


          legend: 'right',
          chartArea: {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%' },

          pieSliceText: 'label',
          pieHole: 0.4,
          colors:['#202020','#282828','#303030','#383838','#404040','#484848','#505050']

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

How to change tools text color "example1" and "example2" in this google visualization PieChart script. i want to color of exactly just "example1" and "example2"

Comment: Can you be more specific? You're trying to change the *text* color for where it says "example1/example2" or are you wanting *all* text in that example to conform to a color? Do you have any more code to show? Pictures/examples of what's happening? More info will definitely help us better assist you. :)

Comment: thank you sir i've update the script i want to changeexactly  just "example1/example2"